# Run Octave script from shell without banner messages

Tags: windows, octave

From the documentation: http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Command-Line-Options.html

> --silent
>   --quiet
>   -q
>
> Don't print the usual greeting and version message at startup.

If I run:

```
C:\Octave-3.6.4x\bin>octave -q --eval 2+3
```

I still get some banner message:

```
 - Use `pkg list' to see a list of installed packages.
 - MSYS shell available (C:\Octave-3.6.4x\msys).
 - Graphics backend: gnuplot.

ans =  5
```

How to disable this banner when running Matlab/Octave script or using eval from command line?

Comment: That banner is not part of Octave at all. It seems that whoever built it modified it to print that extra message. You must enquire who made the build to find where it's coming from or build the original Octave yourself.

Comment: It's the official installer from Octave Forge, the one that most people downloaded: http://sourceforge.net/projects/octave/files/Octave%20Windows%20binaries/

Comment: Octave Forge and Octave are separate (but related) projects. Octave only develops Octave and distributes the source only. Octave Forge develops the packages and offers installers for MinGW and MSVS (because windows is the only OS without a package manager and where building software is a nightmare) but these are not distributed by the Octave project itself. Whoever made your build modified Octave to display that extra info at startup.

Comment: Yep, Mingw/Msys is there for their package system to work, as the program is designed for *nix. Windows on the other hand doesn't need any "package manager", nor I need your ranting about which platform you prefer.

Comment: Have you tried it with `--no-init-file` (or related) option?  One or more of the initialization files might be producing those messages.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. `--no-init-file` had no impact, but `--norc` (or shorter `-f`) cleaned the banner. So for above example: `octave.exe -qf --eval 2+3`

Comment: I had Octave 3.2.4 installed before. In that version -q command line argument makes it produce no output at startup. On the other hand, my new installation of Octave 3.6.4 seems to print those last three lines unconditionally, regardless of the -q option.