# How to run octave script from shell at launch

Tags: matlab, shell, octave

I'm using Ubuntu system. To run MATLAB script at launch, I can type `matlab -nodesktop -r "run ./my_program.m"`.

How can I achieve the same function on Octave, like `octave --no-gui -some_command`?

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35669024/how-to-invoke-octave-script-in-unix-shell) post and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21197944/run-octave-script-from-shell-without-banner-messages) post. They did not answer my question.

Comment: `octave myscript.m`, see https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Invoking-Octave-from-the-Command-Line.html

Comment: How did the first link **not** answer your question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35669024/how-to-invoke-octave-script-in-unix-shell

Comment: Use `octave --help` to see a list of command line options. You are looking for the option `--persist`.

Comment: @jadhachem, @carandraug, The "desired" answer is `octave --persist my_program.m`. Can you post your reply as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned in one of the comment, one solution is:

`octave --persist my_program.m`

Answer (score 4):

Currently looks like it is enough to say for script (not plain function)

`octave my_program.m`

Also if you have octave installed in your path you could and in the beginning of script as the first line the desired interpreter (works for python, bash, whatever), for example for default location :

`#!/usr/bin/octave`

and you can run them without even adding the octave in front... just the script name....

Answer (score 2):

For Windows users:

I see it's a bit harder, since there's no "octave.exe" file.

I do have:
"C:\Program Files\GNU Octave\Octave-6.4.0\mingw64\bin\octave-cli-6.4.0.exe"
which works after adding both parent directories
"C:\Program Files\GNU Octave\Octave-6.4.0\mingw64\bin"
and
"C:\Program Files\GNU Octave\Octave-6.4.0\mingw64"
to PATH.

All this happens automatically in the startup script which is the normal entry point of the SW:

"C:\Program Files\GNU Octave\Octave-6.4.0\octave.vbs"

Finaly, after adding all to path I run it like this:

"C:\Program Files\GNU Octave\Octave-6.4.0\mingw64\bin\octave-cli-6.4.0.exe" "C:\MatlabScripts\matlabScript1.m" c:\temp\myCuteImage.tif [example for prm]